# How does this array initialization shorthand work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
console.log(
  Array.from({ length: 3 }, Function.call, Number)
);
```

According to my understanding, the above code passes `(value, index)` to the `.call` method of the `Function` prototype.

And the `this` value of `.call` is set to `Number`.

So it's exactly the same as:

```js
Array.from({ length: 3 }, (value, index) => Number.call(value, index))
```

In VSCode my tooltip describes the function as:

```js
mapfn: (v: any, k: number) => any
```

That's where I got `(value, index)` from, assuming `k` means `key`/`index`.

But `Number` only accepts a single numerical argument.  So it will accept `value`, and ignore `index`.

But `value` is `undefined`, because the array is not yet initialized.

So how is the code producing an array where each value is equal to its index, instead of full of `NaN`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument `.call` accepts is the `this` value of the function to be invoked. The rest of the arguments are plain arguments that the function gets invoked with. So, this:

```
Number.call(value, index)
```

is equivalent to:

```
Number(index)
```

where the `this` value inside `Number` is set to `value`.

The `value` is indeed undefined, but the Number constructor doesn't care about its calling context, its `this`, so it effectively gets ignored and creates a number from the index.

Here's another way of looking at it: below is a function named `foo`, which, when `.call`ed, does not care about the first parameter, and only takes into consideration the second:

```js
function foo(arg) {
  return 'foo' + arg;
}

console.log(
  foo.call('IGNORED PARAMETER', 'bar')
);
```

Comment: Thanks.  The source of my misunderstanding was actually that I did not know the signature of `.call` implies both the first and second arguments are a sort of `this` argument: `Function.call(this: Function, thisArg: any, ...argArray: any[]): any` It all makes sense now.